# Creating a client-side Ember.js application which also contains the server-side code in the same repository

Tags: node.js, ember.js

I have a code repo that contains a Web application created with *Ember.js*.

However, I would also like to create a server-side application for handling the JSON API. How would this be done? I noticed it's possible because [Ghost does it](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/tree/master/core/).

Comment: Have you looked into Ember-cli-rails? I am using it on my relational blog, and although it can take you some time to learn how things are coupled with each other, maintenance is cheap (in regards to necessary time) and performance seems pretty solid... My project is using JSON API 1.0, but I am not using ruby as API only (which would allow the backend to be even smaller and faster). Project is located at [Deovandski/Fakktion](https://github.com/Deovandski/Fakktion)

Comment: Another option is [EmberFire](https://github.com/firebase/emberFire).

Comment: These are all possibilities but I'm looking for a general solution. I want to have a backend that uses MongoDB and communicates with Ember using the JSON API. So it would be running on Node. And this server-side solution would also have to handle building Ember, I assume.